# how to add two different material in inner and outer side of sink in blender

Tags: texturing, materials

I am trying to add two different materials to the inner and outer sides of the sink, but it appears
only one material in both the outer and inner sides. I added a mixer shader and a geometry node backfacing, but I could not add two materials. I am sharing a screenshot of my work. at a time only one material appears in whole sink both inner and outer sides[image]

[image]

Comment: create 2 materials, then in edit mode select all outer faces, select one material, click "assign", then select inner faces, select the other material, press assign > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk7Vd.gif

Comment: Does your model have a thickness? It's hard to tell, covered by the selection outline. (As a matter of course, debug by temporarily disconnecting all the subtle stuff like image textures, and check out the mix by using something clearly visible.. say, solid blue and solid yellow)